# Adding attachments to email using access based on recordset in form

Tags: vba, email, outlook

im sorry i am a little new here. I have been spending days trying to incorporate my current code which works to send an email based on information in a form. Like a "send email" button. It prefils with the correct information however, my record set has attachments that i cant seem to code properly. ive been reading attachment code for the last 5 days i cant seem to understand how to incorporate it in my current code. I would just like the attachment that is saved in my record to be included in my email. Here is my current code, could someone walk me through how to include an attachment code in there? Thank you so much in advance!!

```
    Private Sub btnEmail_Click()

      Dim objOutlook As Object
      Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
      Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
      Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment

      ' Create the Outlook session.
      Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

      ' Create the message.
      Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

      With objOutlookMsg
          ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Nancy Davolio")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

          ' Add the CC recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Michael Suyama")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olCC

         ' Add the BCC recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Andrew Fuller")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olBCC

         ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
         .Subject = "This is an Automation test with Microsoft Outlook"
         .Body = "This is the body of the message."
         .Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance


         ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
         For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
             objOutlookRecip.Resolve
         Next

         ' Should we display the message before sending?

             .Display

            ' .Save
            ' .Send

      End With
      Set objOutlook = Nothing

    End Sub


    Function SaveAttachment()
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
 Dim rstAttachment As DAO.Recordset2
 Dim fld As DAO.Field2
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim intz As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
     Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("site inspections table", dbOpenDynaset)
     rst.FindFirst "ID = " & Me!ID
      Set rstAttachment = rst.Fields("Photos").Value
     Set fld = rstAttachment.Fields("Filedata")
     strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Attach\" _
     & rstAttachment.Fields("Filename")
     On Error Resume Next
     Kill strPath & "\Attach\"
     On Error GoTo 0

     fld.SaveToFile strPath

 rstAttachment.Close
 rst.Close
 Set rstAttachment = Nothing
 Set rst = Nothing
 Set db = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()
 Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim outlookNamespace As NameSpace
 Dim objMailItem  As MailItem
 Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
 Dim strAttachementPath As String
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
 Dim rstAttachment As DAO.Recordset2
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim strHTML

'Call SaveAttachment
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
 Set objFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set objMailItem = objFolder.Items.Add(olMailItem)
    Set db = CurrentDb
     Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("site inspections table", dbOpenDynaset)
     rst.FindFirst "ID = " & Me!ID
    Set rstAttachment = rst.Fields("Photos").Value
'strAttachementPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Attach\" _
' & rstAttachment.Fields("Filename")

' Build HTML for message body.
 strHTML = "<HTML><HEAD>"
 strHTML = "<br>"
 strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Face=Calibri><b>ID: </b></br>" & [ID] & "<br>"
 strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Face=Calibri><b>Date: </b></br>" & [Date] & "<br>"
 strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Face=Calibri><b>Time: </b></br>" & [Time] & "<br>"
 strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Face=Calibri><b>Technician: </b></br>" & [Technician] & "<br>"
 strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Face=Calibri><b>Area: </b></br>" & [Area] & "<br>"
 strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Face=Calibri><b>Blast No.: </b></br>" & [shot number] & "<br><br>"
 strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Face=Calibri><b>Comments: </b></br>" & [Comments] & "<br>"
 strHTML = strHTML & "</FONT></br><BODY>"
'strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Face=Arial Color=#ff0000 Size=5>Job #: 123456</FONT></br>"
'strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Size=3>For: <FONT Size=2></B>a name here</br>"
'strHTML = strHTML & "<FONT Size=3><B>Description: </B><FONT Size=2>description of work to be                                         
 strHTML = strHTML & "</BODY></HTML>"

' Build the Email to be sent
With objMailItem
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .To = "EMAIL ADDRESS HERE"
    .Subject = "Site Inspection for " & [Area] & " At " & [Date]
'    .Body = "Some text here"
    .HTMLBody = strHTML
' Grab Attachments for Email if there are any
    If rstAttachment.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Call SaveAttachment
        strAttachementPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Attach\" _
        & rstAttachment.Fields("Filename")
        .Attachments.Add (strAttachementPath)
    End If
     .Display
 End With

 outlookApp.ActiveWindow
 'SendKeys ("%s")
MsgBox "Mail Sent!", vbOKOnly, "Mail Sent"
```

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: Please provide the attachment code that you tried to incorporate.

Comment: Well ive got error codes like compile errors from a callAttachment line. But honestly the codes ive tried are the ones ive found from google. Im not near my laptop at the moment is be happy to get the code i was trying to get to work together tmr, i deleted it out of frustration. Was hoping someone might be able to supply me the code to add into the existing one i have to account for adding attachments.  What ill do it make another round at it and paste the code im using with the errors, that probably make more sense. Thanks guys ill get it back tmr

Answer (score 0):

```
objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyTestFile.txt")
```

is all it takes.

Comment: Oh thank u! but How do i make it so it loads the attachment thats linked to the record set  saved in tblCustomers that i have focused on my form?

Comment: You will need to save the blob to a temporary file, call Attachments.Add, delete the temporary file.

Comment: So is the process that the attachment saved in access needs to be saved to a temporary folder or file then called on by code to load into the email then delete the temp file? if so i think i found this code on google to try to incorporate that process but im having trouble translating it to incorporate it into my current project. Can someone help me figure out what i need to change to make it work with my project? i have tblCustomers with a field called "attachments". Here is the code thank u in advance!

Comment: So what is the code and what happens when you run it?